# How can I easily find the synonyms I've suggested?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-synonyms, usability, navigation

It's hard to find the /tags/synonyms URL. Filtering by username from there is not obvious as well. It would be nice if there was a link on the profile page.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a query on data.SE for this purpose:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/158542/my-tag-synonyms